# Is it valid JavaScript to nest an if/else in a switch?

Tags: javascript

Is this valid?

```
switch(foo) {
    case 'bar':
    if(raz == 'something') {
        // execute
    } else {
        // do something else
    }
    break;
    ...
    default:
    // yada yada
}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes, [it is perfectly valid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch). Have you tried it?

Comment: Trying something and having it work doesn't necessarily mean it's valid. It could just be something that falls through the cracks but is not appropriate. Tons of things in the web world aren't "valid" markup or code but they function in one way or another.

Comment: JavaScript is less of a voodoo magic thing, IMO. Statements associated with a case *can* be anything - I have yet to see a counter-example.

Comment: @ karim79 & Bertrand Marron - I did try it in some code i was working on earlier. It didn't work, but I think it may have been due to something else.  I changed it to pure if/else everywhere and made other changes as well.  It could be that the other changes is what made it start working and not the changing to the if/else.

Comment: There's also [this](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/jscript/ch06_05.htm) in case (haha) anyone is interested.

Answer (score 15):

You can combine a `switch` and an `if` in a better way, if you really have to:

```
switch (true) {
    case (foo === 'bar' && raz === 'something'):
        // execute
        break;
    case (foo === 'bar'):
        // do something else
        break;
    default:
        // yada yada
}
```

<sub>*Sorry to revive such an old post, but it may help people who came here looking how to combine or nest a `switch` and an `if` statement.*</sub>

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. You can just use an if/else if statement and remove the surrounding switch case...

Comment: It *does* make sense. When using a `return` in each of the `case`s, you can skip `break;`, and it can be a very readable replacement for long `if/else` statements.

Comment: An if else statement automatically breaks if one condition is fulfilled...

Answer (score 1):

and you can also use `ternary if` wrapped inside a `return` statement

```
   switch(foo) {
        case 'bar':
          return(
            (raz == 'something') ? 
              // excute
            : 
              // do something else
          )
        break;
        ...
        default:
        // yada yada
    }
```